# How to execute one line multiple times using Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Below is my requirement.

```
@echo off
cls
Set Sleep=0
:start
echo This is a loop
xx.exe yyyyy.dll /p:InputDataSource=Table:table.xml
Set /A Sleep+=1
echo DisplayingSleepvalue
echo %Sleep%
goto start
```

Here I want to execute `xx.exe yyyyy.dll /p:InputDataSource=Table:table.xml` this line for **30 times**....
Could any one please help me on this.

Thanks,
Manasa

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this way:-

```
@echo off
cls
Set Sleep=0
:start
if %Sleep% == 30 ( goto end )
xx.exe yyyyy.dll /p:InputDataSource=Table:table.xml
echo This is a loop
Set /A Sleep+=1
echo %Sleep%
goto start
:end
echo "am 30 now"
pause
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use a `GOTO` loop with an incrementing counter, but a `FOR /L` loop is much more efficient.

```
for /l %%N in (1 1 30) do someCommand
```

Study the documentation available by typing `HELP FOR` or `FOR /?` from the command line.

If you want to repeat the whole block of code, then enclose the block in parentheses. You can use the `FOR` `%%N` variable in place of the `Sleep` variable.

```
@echo off
cls
for /l %%N in (1 1 30) do (
  echo This is a loop
  xx.exe yyyyy.dll /p:InputDataSource=Table:table.xml
  echo DisplayingSleepvalue
  echo %%N
)
```

It is not needed with your example, but if you want to manipulate an environment variable within a loop, then you must use delayed expansion. Normal expansion `%sleep%` is only expanded once when the entire loop is parsed, whereas you need the `!sleep!` value to be expanded at execution time for each loop iteration. Delayed expansion must be enabled before it can be used.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
cls
set sleep=0
for /l %%N in (1 1 30) do (
  echo This is a loop
  xx.exe yyyyy.dll /p:InputDataSource=Table:table.xml
  set /a sleep+=1
  echo DisplayingSleepvalue
  echo !sleep!
)
```

Comment: I tried this for loop, but I am unaware of "pause" and was stuck at this. Now after giving this pause, its working fine

Answer (score 2):

You've got the loop, just add some math.

```
@echo off
set executecounter=0
:loop
(Insert your command here)
set /a executecounter=%executecounter%+1
if "%executecounter%"=="30" goto done
goto loop
:done
echo Complete!
pause
```

This will increase the counter every time the command executes, and when it has executed 30 times, the program will end.