# How to open more than 1000 SSH sessions at one click using PuTTY?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

I want to open 1000 SSH sessions from remote server using PuTTY in Windows 10 for test purposes. How to do that in an easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a batch file like this:

```
for /l %%N in (1 1 1000) do putty.exe -load "your session"
```

Based on: [How to execute one line multiple times using windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10072879/850848)